# Error: unexpected symbol in " ON a.guest_id"

Tags: sql, regex, sqlite

```
sqldf('Select a.guest_id,case when b.guest_id is not null then 'old' else 'new' end as tagging from JDUniqueGuestid as a
left join UniqueGuestidallsource b
ON a.guest_id = b.guest_id', drv="SQLite")
```

After running the above code getting below mentioned error, kindly help me and resolve the issue

> Error: unexpected symbol in "      ON a.guest_id"

Comment: sqldf('Select a.guest_id,case when b.guest_id is not null then 'old' else 'new' end as tagging from JDUniqueGuestid as a
left join UniqueGuestidallsource b
ON a.guest_id = b.guest_id', drv="SQLite")

Comment: you have single quotes around the whole query, but also single quotes within the query; it's not being parsed the way you intend it to

Answer (score 1):

You have single quotes around the whole query, but also single quotes within the query; it's not being parsed the way you intend it to.

Depending on the larger context, something like this might work:

```
"Select a.guest_id, case ... 'old' else 'new' ... ON a.guest_id = b.guest_id"
```

or you might need to escape the single quotes with something like this:

```
'Select a.guest_id, case ... \'old\' else \'new\' ... ON a.guest_id = b.guest_id'
```

It depends on the context in which that query string appears, and how it parses quoted strings.